# Asynchronous AWS Lambda Call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda which is triggered by an S3 push event. The lambda will call an API which will trigger a long-running process. I recognize that I can configure S3 to invoke the lambda function asynchronously, and so S3 will not wait for a response, but I am interested to find out if I can configure lambda to call my API asynchronously as well. I don't want lambda waiting for several minutes while the process completes. Can anyone point me to some documentation which outlines this process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call the api? What code do you have? What language? This is unrelated to AWS lambda but is a general programming question instead: can I run an http request and intentionally not wait for its response? What do you want to do if the request fails after 2 minutes?

Comment: The call is made from the python script in the lambda. So this is a programming feature rather than a lambda configuration? That does make sense. 

If there is a failure to reach the API, an email is sent out to operations team.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Lambda can do this nor would I recommend a workaround. There is an [article on SenseDeep](https://www.sensedeep.com/blog/posts/stories/lambda-fast-http.html) which talks about this and specifically points out that points out "So what happens if we simply do not call "await" and thus not wait on the response from our HTTP request?" - "Strange things happen" - which is to say that invoking an async call in a lambda then returning immediately has unpredictable results.

Why do you need the Lambda to return quickly? If there is a valid reason (for example, you want a push notification that something in S3 has changed right away), then I'd recommend a different pattern.

1. Updating S3 triggers a lambda
2. That lambda writes to an SNS topic and does whatever fast action you want
3. There is a subscriber to the SNS topic that does the long running action you want

Comment: This is good feedback. The reason why we want lambda to return right away, is that the process it calls can take several minutes to complete, and we don't want lambda waiting for a response all that time. It's not cost-efficient. I think either the SNS topic or using SQS are good ideas, and as well, the lambda code is written in python. The suggestion was made above to make the asynchronous call with python rather than configure it in lambda.